# What are the line thicknesses for fractions and underlines?

Tags: fonts

I need to know the thickness of certain lines in my document. In particular I want to know the thickness of the rule in a display-fraction and the thickness of an underline. I want to pass one of these values to another package so that it draws various lines with the same thickness. I think the thickness depends on the font, because `stix2` has much thicker underlines compared to the default font.

Comment: Please, can you add a picture to understand your question?

Answer (score 3):

The `\fontdimen8\textfont3` is the internal font register where the rule thickness is saved. Try:

```
\the \fontdimen8\textfont3 % default value of used font

$a\over b$

\fontdimen8\textfont3=1pt

$a\over b$
```

But LuaTeX uses another method to access such values. See section 7.4.1 of LuaTeX manual.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know this was engine dependent. I am using XeLaTeX with fontspec. Currently I get ! Font \nullfont has only 7 fontdimen parameters.

Comment: @user100361 Because you are using LaTeX, you must load the math font by first usage of math mode. This is LaTeX specific, that math fonts are loaded after first `$...$`.

Comment: @user100361 I have tried to use LaTeX format (when you mention XeLaTeX) and it is fact that you have to load math fonts before manipulating with `\fondimen`s in LaTeX. LaTeX format does not preloads math fonts. You can load these fonts by `\setbox0=\hbox{$$}` in the preamble.